# Can't receive post parameters from extjs ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I'm trying to persist grid updates to database, so I write in my controller:

```
    //...
    editUser: function(button, eventObj) {   
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(this.getSelected());
},

getSelected: function() {
    var grid = this.getUserList();
    var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
    return selectedRecord;
},
updateUser: function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'),
            form = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values);
    form.updateRecord();
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
}
});
```

And this is my store code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'MyApp.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods:
            {create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'},
    api: {
        create: 'data/createUser.php',
        read: 'data/getUsers.php',
        update: 'data/updateUser.php',
        destroy: 'data/deleteUser.php'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
```

});

When I hit "save" button firebug tells me that POST request has been sent to my php file, but when I
print_r($_POST) in php it shows me an empty array. How can this be?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the proxy's [writer](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json) will send the JSON string as raw POST data to the server. PHP's `$_POST` superglobal takes variables/parameters from the raw POST data, if possible, e.g. if it contains url-encoded data:

```
var1=a&var2=b&var3=c
```

However, since your POST data is just a JSON string, there are no key=value pairs to extract from, which is why your `$_POST` array is empty.

To read the raw post data, you can use PHP's input stream [`php://input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

Alternatively, in ExtJS you can also tell the writer to pass the JSON string as a HTTP parameter to the request using the [`encode`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-encode) and [`root`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-root) configurations:

```
proxy: {
    // ...
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        encode: true,
        root: 'users'
    }
}
```

Which will result in the writer generating the POST data like this:

```
users={"var1":"a","var2":"b","var3":"c"}
```

and therefore allows you to use the `$_POST` variable in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['users']);
var_dump($data);
```